# Updating Droid X running leaked Gingerbread to official release without root

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, updates, motorola-droid-x

I have a stock unrooted Droid X running a leaked version of the Gingerbread update (system version 4.5.588). How can I update to the official release (system version 4.5.596) without root?

Comment: If you're running a leaked ROM, you've already voided your warranty. Why don't you want to root?

Comment: Can I root without wiping my device?

Comment: @Skywalker Generally speaking, yes. I haven't looked very far into methods of rooting the Droid X, though.

Comment: i used z4root to root my brothers Droid X (I don't know of it's availability any more, but i am sure you can find it if you google it). It was as easy as installing the app, and clicking "root". No data loss at all.

Comment: zroot isn't working for me with the official gingerbread release.

Comment: GingerBreak does work however

Answer (score 1):

There should be someone who has the official release that you can download and just upgrade like you did with the leaked version.  [Like this post here](http://www.droid-life.com/2011/05/28/download-official-droidx-gingerbread-4-5-596-for-rooted-users/).  It says it's for rooted users, but I don't see anything in the instructions that should require root.

Comment: "When you finish with this process, whether you are coming from Froyo or a leaked GB, you will be on official .596 with root access." This doesn't help someone who doesn't want to have root at the end of the process.

Answer (score 0):

You going to want to sbf your phone back to .340 first. [Here](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/droid-x-rooted-help/112152-maderstcok-ota-2-3-340-update-zip.html) is a great forum post showing how. I did it with my linux box, you can do it with windows but drivers can be an issue from what I have heard. Once you sbf your phone you can pull it down OTA. Warning this erases everything and you will loose root. The official release has not been rooted yet to my knowledge.

I have done it 2 times now I was running lexlite gingerade and sbf to install leaked gingerbread and then I sbf to install the offical release.

**Edit: ** Looks like I was wrong it has been rooted there is just no easy root method. See @CaseyB post.

Let me know if you need any more help.